# Is it possible to know facebook logout in mobile browser in iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook

I have Facebook sharing implemented in my app.

These are the scenarios:

> - I don't have Facebook app installed in my device, so the Facebook    must be logged in from mobile browser and it will ask authentication.
> - I do some sharing from my app.
> - I logout my Facebook account from mobile browser.
> - Want to do FB share again from my app, it doesn't ask me the login and authentication page again, but it displays the sharing dialog.

Can i revoke the access token or invalidate the session when the Facebook website is logged out from mobile browser?